# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getReference() on null in

Tags: php, firebase

I am trying PHP to firebase insertion but I have got this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getReference()
>   on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\makatravel1\Account.php:44 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\makatravel1\Account.php(72): Account->insert(Array) #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\makatravel1\Account.php on line 44

This is the code that I am trying to run-

```
class Account{
    protected $database;
    protected $dbname = "users";

    public function __construct(){
        $acc = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'./firebase/key/makatravel2019-34ec2f4b7a9c.json');

        $firebase = (new Factory)
            ->withServiceAccount($acc)
            ->create();

        $database = $firebase->getDatabase();
    }

    public function insert(array $data){
        if(empty($data) || !isset($data)){
            return FALSE;
        }

        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $this->database->getReference()->getChild($this->dbname)->getChild($key)->set($value);
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
}



$users = new Account();

var_dump($users ->insert([
    '1' => 'John',
    '2' => 'Doe'
]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error tells you that there is a problem with *`getReference()` on `null`*. You have one `getReference()` call in your code:

```
$this->database->getReference()->getChild($this->dbname)->getChild($key)->set($value);
```

The error states that there is a problem with `$this->database`, it is 'undefined' (null). However, you clearly defined it at the top of your class:

```
protected $database;
```

Then you try to set this variable in your constructor method:

```
$database = $firebase->getDatabase();
```

However, this is not how you should "address" the variable. You should use `$this` like you did with the call that results in the error:

```
$this->database = $firebase->getDatabase();
```